# How to create a home button on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a home button that can be used on every window and direct me back to home, in Python without OOP.

Comment: Ok, you say you want to create a home button. What's stopping you? Create a button, label it "Home", and have it call a function. What part of that do you need help with?

Comment: Why not OOP, isn't this the text book case for it? You need a single object to use in multiple parent objects, because that object does exactly the same thing for it all?

Comment: maybe you need rather one window with many "pages" which you can replace in window. And then you would need only one button to go back to "home" page.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This could work:

```
import Tkinter as tk
win1 = tk.Tk()
win2 = tk.Tk()
win3 = tk.Tk()
win4 = tk.Tk()
def home_button():
    print("Home Button Pressed.")
tk.Button(win1, text="home", command=home_button).pack()
tk.Button(win2, text="home", command=home_button).pack()
tk.Button(win3, text="home", command=home_button).pack()
tk.Button(win4, text="home", command=home_button).pack()
win1.mainloop()
win2.mainloop()
win3.mainloop()
win4.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not create more than one instance of `Tk`, nor call `mainloop` more than once.

Comment: It was the only solution I could think of.